# Sorting XML in XSLT based on a list of values

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I'd like to sort one XML file with an XSL transformation.

```
<root>
   <element>
        <name>A</name>
   </element>
   <element>
        <name>B</name>
   </element>
   <element>
        <name>C</name>
   </element>
</root>
```

Must be sorted by the following list of names: C, A, B so that the resulting XML is:

```
 <root>
       <element>
            <name>C</name>
       </element>
       <element>
            <name>A</name>
       </element>
       <element>
            <name>B</name>
       </element>
    </root>
```

Obviously the list of values to be sort on should be quite dynamic (parameter of the XSLT, another XML file...).
Any idea how to do that in the XSLT ?

Thanks,
Christophe

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution, plus exhaustive explanations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSortingValues" select="'C,A,B'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vSortingValues" select=
  "concat(',', $pSortingValues, ',')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "string-length(substring-before($vSortingValues,concat(',',name,',')))"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <name>A</name>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>B</name>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>C</name>
    </element>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results**:

```
<root>
   <element>
      <name>C</name>
   </element>
   <element>
      <name>A</name>
   </element>
   <element>
      <name>B</name>
   </element>
</root>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The desired sorted values list is the `pSortingValues` global parameter**, which can be provided externally to the transformation.
2. **The identity rule is used to copy all nodes "as-is".**
3. **The identity rule is overriden for the top element**. The top element is partially copied, its attributes are copied, then templates are applied on all children-elements with an `<xsl:sort>` child instruction, which specifies the exact sort key to be used -- how in front of the `pSortingValues` values the name of the `element` child is.

**UPDATE**: As noted by @Alejandro, this:

```
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "string-length(substring-before($vSortingValues,concat(',',name,',')))"/>
```

may be simplified to this:

```
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
        "substring-before($vSortingValues,concat(',',name,','))"/>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Good answer. As string data types, the substring before works in the same way, also.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks. I *am* using `substring-before()`.

Comment: @Dimitre: Ja! Yes, I saw. I meant without `fn:string-length()` nor `@data-type="number"`

Comment: @Alejandro: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Dimitre: Sorry, yes. Like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401774/sorting-xpath-results-in-the-same-order-as-multiple-select-parameters/4402105#4402105) : `xsl:sort select="substring-before($vSortingValues,concat(',',name,','))"` would be enough.

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't see how this will be correct -- the individual values are not in sorted order.

Comment: I'd like to see an explanation for this  that uses 'for-each' instead of templates?

Comment: @JonH: You'd like what ??? Why would any sane person replace `xsl:apply-templates` with `xsl:for-each` ? Of course, this *can* be done, but why such replacement is necessary? Also, such a replacement isn't "explanation", so I am deeply confused by your comment...