# BizTalk XSLT Mapping For Grouping and Sorting with Multiple Records

Tags: xslt, biztalk

Input Message :

The Input File Has Three Records inside the Detail is in the order “Member” , “Product” and “Dependent” , In each Record there is a common Field which is “ Identifier” For Some reason we getting like Each Member and Product are looped into one detail and Each dependent is looping into separate Detail
................................................................................

```
    <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="Test">
  <Detail>
    <Member>
      <Name>Jerry</Name>
      <Address>Miami</Address>
      <PhoneNumber>7008084201</PhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Member>
    <Product>
      <Name>Phone</Name>
      <Type>Personal</Type>
      <Serial>000000111111</Serial>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Product>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Tom</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>7228084302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Tom1</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>8228084302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Tom2</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>9228084302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Member>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Address>Kansas</Address>
      <PhoneNumber>5007684306</PhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>699039521</Identifier>
    </Member>
    <Product>
      <Name>Xbox</Name>
      <Type>Personal</Type>
      <Serial>000000222222</Serial>
      <Identifier>699039521</Identifier>
    </Product>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Member>
      <Name>Larry</Name>
      <Address>Newjersey</Address>
      <PhoneNumber>6004567307</PhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Member>
    <Product>
      <Name>Iphone</Name>
      <Type>Personal</Type>
      <Serial>0000003333333</Serial>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Product>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Luis</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>7897684302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>LuisMead</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>7229876302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
  </Detail>
</ns0:Root>
```

Expected OutPut XML :

The OutPut File is also Similar to the Input File but the order is  “Member” , “Dependent” and “Product” . The Common Field “Identifier” is the common on in this case also.The idea is to make Detail to loop on “Member” , “Dependent” and “Product” order.
......................................................................................

```
    <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="Test">
  <Detail>
    <Member>
      <Name>Jerry</Name>
      <Address>Miami</Address>
      <PhoneNumber>7008084201</PhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Member>

    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Tom</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>7228084302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Tom1</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>8228084302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Tom2</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>9228084302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
    <Product>
      <Name>Phone</Name>
      <Type>Personal</Type>
      <Serial>000000111111</Serial>
      <Identifier>225692067</Identifier>
    </Product>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Member>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Address>Kansas</Address>
      <PhoneNumber>5007684306</PhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>699039521</Identifier>
    </Member>
    <Product>
      <Name>Xbox</Name>
      <Type>Personal</Type>
      <Serial>000000222222</Serial>
      <Identifier>699039521</Identifier>
    </Product>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Member>
      <Name>Larry</Name>
      <Address>Newjersey</Address>
      <PhoneNumber>6004567307</PhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Member>

    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>Luis</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>7897684302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
    <Dependent>
      <DependentName>LuisMead</DependentName>
      <DependentAddress>Miami</DependentAddress>
      <DependentPhoneNumber>7229876302</DependentPhoneNumber>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Dependent>
    <Product>
      <Name>Iphone</Name>
      <Type>Personal</Type>
      <Serial>0000003333333</Serial>
      <Identifier>230903815</Identifier>
    </Product>
  </Detail>

</ns0:Root>
```

Need Suggestion on writing XSLT 1.0 Code for this.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: The Input File Has Three Records inside the Detail is in the order “Member” , “Product” and “Dependent” , For Some reason we getting like Each Member and Product are looped into one detail and Each dependent is looping into separate Detail. It needs to be formated in a way where the order will be  “Member” ,  “Dependent” and “Product” and Come as one Group Detail. The Common Field on all the records is " identifier"

Comment: Add this to your question, along with your current XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in XSLT-1.0 with *Muenchian Grouping*. Search for it on StackOverflow and you will find a lot of examples. Applying it created the following answer:

- Create an `xsl:key` with the nodes `Member|Dependent|Product` using its `Identifier` element value as a key
- Create a *sortingOrder* variable which provides indices for sorting the entries in the inner `xsl:for-each`
- Match and copy the root node `/ns0:Root` with a template
- Loop over all children of the `Detail` elements in a `xsl:for-each`. The expression applies the *Muenchian Grouping* method
- Create a `Detail` elements and loop over the results of the previous `xsl:for-each` sorted by the index of the occurrence of the name of the current element in the *sortingOrder* variable. Copy its content. The method of ordering the elements was taken [from this SO answer: "Sorting XML in XSLT based on a list of values"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786814/1305969).

The stylesheet could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="Test">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="id" match="Member|Dependent|Product" use="Identifier" />   
<xsl:variable name="sortingOrder" select="'Member,Dependent,Product'" />

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Detail/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('id',Identifier)[1])]">
            <Detail>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('id',Identifier)">
                    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="string-length(substring-before($sortingOrder,local-name()))" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Detail>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be as desired.